# Acces to my PC from hostile Access Point

Tags: wireless, security

I connected to a Wifi access point that had cloned my SSID.

I did not enter my ubuntu password during the connection, since I did not install anything. I just used Firefox for several minutes.

Is there any theoretical chance of anybody accessing my data or changing anything in the system or BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

All* the risk lies with web stuff. There are possible attack vectors that you may have been exposed to:

- Unsecure web traffic was probably logged, cookies read. This allows people to log in as you on websites that aren't using HTTPS. This usually isn't a reset-your-password thing but you do need to invalidate your old sessions. How this works is largely dependent on the website.
- See any certificate errors? If you did, your HTTPS traffic was also likely compromised.
- Chat clients are habitually a bit weaker. IRC can use SSL but usually wont by default. Skype (and others from its generation) should be fine.

Software installation and updates (through the repos) are largely unaffected by bad networks because everything is signed. Package lists need to match up with their keys. Package hashes need to match up with their package lists. It's hard to properly interfere with that process.

If the SSID is still out there, download a Wifi scanner on your phone (many exist) and follow the signal strength. Get a good idea where it's coming from and then call the police. The person you've found is committing a fairly serious crime.

<sub>* Assuming you don't have open services inside your network (eg you have a server on your laptop that "trusts" anything with the same subnet). If you do (and some people do - I do but I'm wired) the level of risk depends on what you're running but I doubt there are many automated SSID-clone-hackers out there which will probe you too thoroughly.</sub>

Comment: I just installed Ubuntu and did not change anything... so I hope there is really no open service or something like that. But as i know the computer is logging to wifi even before the password to Ubuntu pc is entered, which means - I enter the password/login to my pc during I have already been connected to wrong access point.On the internet I just checked somethin, whithout entering eny passwords... so is there still any chace?

Comment: As I say, it doesn't matter so much about password entry (though that does matter), it's more about cookie hijacking. That won't get you into a banking website but it will get you into somebody's Facebook profile or webmail.